# Passing an argument from HTML Form to PHP

Tags: php, html, arguments

Here is the HTML Form:

```
<form action="imagematch.php" method="get">
Input Route Number: <input type="text" name="N" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

And here is the PHP file:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET[’N’]))
{
$N = $_GET[’N’];
}
?>
```

Right now, it is reading the PHP file but it isn't reading the "N" argument correctly.

Comment: Maybe it's because you are using ’ instead of ' or  " as your quotation marks?

Comment: Yes $_GET[’N’] must be like $_GET['N'], issue seems with single quote only

Comment: Also before your if condition, you can debug like print_r($_GET); die; to check if $_GET data is coming.

Answer (score -1):

As best we can tell, the issue seems to be the type of quotes you are using around the letter 'N'. This is very common when copying code from webpages. The angled/curly quotes used in webpages aren't interpreted the same as quotes expected and accepted in most programming languages. If you look at [this article](https://practicaltypography.com/straight-and-curly-quotes.html), you can see the difference. Note you want to do the opposite of what they recommend as they are making recommendations for publications and not code. You want to use straight quotes only in code.

As a separate recommendation, as mentioned by joeDaigle, you should use the GET method for when you are GETting (or reading) information, and use PUT when PUTting (or writing/updating) information. You can read [this RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4) for more details, but the main reason is that browsers treat GET and POST requests differently (note when you refresh a regular webpage, versus when you refresh a page after submitting a POST form and your browser prompts asking if you're sure).